# How select correct answer if there were few?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I have situation - there were few answers on my question. Both are not what I need, not complete solution at least, but both of them gave me idea for right solution. What should I do?

Comment: You could upvote those other answers and then answer your own question with the actual solution you did, and accept that. As long as your final solution isn't too similar to one of the answers (even if they gave you the right idea) I would think this is fine.

Comment: Select answer on the basis of usefulness .... if ine answer solve problem in correct manner than accept it ..and letter if you found that there is other better answer then accept  newer one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many options to choose from, in a case-by-case basis:

- If you feel you could accept either without feeling bad about accepting it, just accept one. Toss a coin if you really can't decide.
- Upvote the helpful answers, then add your own to-the-point answer, which answers your specific question.
- Choose the answer which can be better edited to be complete, edit it yourself, then accept it once/if edit is approved.
- Choose the answer which is closer, then ask the answerer to add the details you are missing.
- Just leave the question unaccepted. Nothing wrong with that, if you think you didn't get a complete enough answer.
- If you can do it without invalidating any of the answers, then I suppose you could also carefully edit the question to match the answers, so you can accept one.